# Delete multiple Files in Explorer from Excel

Tags: windows, excel, vba, explorer

I'm trying to select around 17k files in a specific folder containing around 22k from a list in excel. The list has the name and extension of all files and nothing more.

I've tried this code but no luck.

```
Sub DeletePics()
    Dim picRNG As Range, pic As Range, picPATH As String

    picPATH = "path"
    Set picRNG = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A17108").SpecialCells(xlConstants)

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each pic In picRNG
        If pic.Offset(, 1) = "Delete" Then
            If Len(Dir(picPATH & pic.Value)) > 0 Then
                Kill picPATH & pic.Value
                pic.Offset(, 2).Value = "Deleted"
            Else
                pic.Offset(, 2).Value = "Not Found"
            End If
        End If
    Next pic
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [Loop files acording to name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376702/loop-files-acording-to-name/31377326#31377326).

Comment: Nope, I only need a macro to select the files in Windows explorer based on a list on excel. 
The files are all on the same folder with complete extension. They're all jpg.

Comment: So what do you plan to do with them? Selecting them in Explorer makes no sense without some ultimate purpose and that purpose is very likely better performed within the same procedure rather than 'selecting' them in Explorer. (and yes, that code does create a list of files; you just need to change a few things so that they are .JPGs and not .XLSs. Did you even bother to look at it?)

Comment: Many thanks for your help once more.
I think the simplest task would be delete them...

Comment: Ok I'll try to delete the files, I think that will be easier

Comment: What is the problem? If you step through that by tapping [F8], what is the value (hover over to get) of picPATH and  pic.Value? What is the actual path you want to use? It cannot be `"Path"`. (btw, the code looks pretty good)

Comment: Yes I know, the path is the actual path of the pics.
What's wrong... I ran the macro but the pics still there :)

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see what error you are getting. It may be a malformed file path (no `\\` on the end) or perhaps a file permissions error.